# unable to use autoregressor function in Vertica using own data

Tags: vertica, autoregressive-models

I am new to both `datascience` and `vertica`. I am following this example on `autoregressor` from `Vertica` documentation

https://www.vertica.com/docs/11.0.x/HTML/Content/Authoring/AnalyzingData/MachineLearning/TimeSeries/AutoregressorExample.htm?tocpath=Analyzing%20Data%7CMachine%20Learning%20for%20Predictive%20Analytics%7CRegression%20Algorithms%7C_____1

If I understood correctly, I need to provide a training data to the model and use the model to make predictions.

The training data looks like this (day of a year and temperature on the day)

```
select * from temp_data limit 10;
        time         | Temperature
---------------------+-------------
 1981-01-01 00:00:00 |        20.7
 1981-01-02 00:00:00 |        17.9
 1981-01-03 00:00:00 |        18.8
 1981-01-04 00:00:00 |        14.6
 1981-01-05 00:00:00 |        15.8
 1981-01-06 00:00:00 |        15.8
 1981-01-07 00:00:00 |        15.8
 1981-01-08 00:00:00 |        17.4
 1981-01-09 00:00:00 |        21.8
 1981-01-10 00:00:00 |          20
(10 rows)
```

I create the model `SELECT AUTOREGRESSOR('AR_temperature', 'temp_data', 'Temperature', 'time' USING PARAMETERS p=3);`

Question 1 - The example uses `temp_data` table for predictions as well? Why? Isn't `temp_data` used for `training` and I should use a `test` data which doesn't has `Temperature` column?

```
SELECT PREDICT_AUTOREGRESSOR(Temperature USING PARAMETERS model_name='AR_temperature', npredictions=10) OVER(ORDER BY time) FROM temp_data; <-- why does the example use temp_data
```

Question 2 - I created my own table with a day. When I use it to make a prediction, I get error

```
select * from my_temperature_data;
        time         | temperature
---------------------+-------------
 2021-12-12 00:00:00 |

select predict_autoregressor(temperature using parameters model_name='ar_temperature') over(order by time) from my_temperature_data;
ERROR 5861:  Error calling processPartition() in User Function predict_autoregressor at [src/Autoregression/PredictAR.cpp:149], error code: 0, message: One or more elements in the input data is invalid.
```

Question 3 - When I made my own table, I had to make it with both `Time` and `temperature` columns. Just having `Time` didn't work (got error). Why?

Answer (score 0):

Please find the answers below

1. You are right. test data should have been used
2. As mentioned in the documentation OVER clause is mandatory with timestamp column because previous timestamps are taken into consideration. Since your query doesn't have a over() clause, it failed with that error.
   https://www.vertica.com/docs/11.0.x/HTML/Content/Authoring/SQLReferenceManual/Functions/MachineLearning/PREDICT_AUTOREGRESSOR.htm
3. As mentioned in 2, you need to pass both temperature and time for PREDICT_AUTOREGRESSOR to work.